# After affects transition help

Tags: after-effects, transitions

I need to do a transition that puts random circles that expand over a video but each circle needs to start at random times.

Does anyone know the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Do these circles act as a wipe between two full screen images, or do they contain individual images, or...? Does each circle cover only a portion of the screen, or would each eventually expand to cover the whole screen? Details, please -- maybe a drawing?

Comment: Two full screen images

Comment: I apologize Jim, I was checking on my phone and only saw half of your comment. Yes, it is two full screen images. Each circle only needs to grow to a certain size say 75 pixels but there needs to be enough to fill the screen at the end of the transition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the particle engine CC Particle World.

Set the particles to be shaded spheres, adjust the X&Y radius of the producer to fill the screen, adjust the birth rate to produce particles at the rate you need, turn off gravity and velocity.  set the end size to be so big that they fill the screen.  Set the Particle Transfer Mode to "black matte", and you'll get something like this:

[image]

then precomp the particle layer, moving everything inside the comp

Now add your two layers (the files for before & after the transition). Put the "before" layer at the bottom, then the "after" layer, then the "particle" comp layer.
Turn of the particle layer by clicking the eyeball.
In the example below, I'm using a pink and blue layer for the before and after.

Add a "[Set Matte](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/channel-effects.html#set_matte_effect)" to the "after" layer, and set the "Take matte from layer" setting to your particle layer.

When you drag through the comp, your "before" layer should reveal the "after" layer via your circles.

[image]

Comment: That sound perfect i will try this asap. Thanks tomh. This takes me back to my days of playing with particles in Lightwave 3d.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to construct a matte layer out of white circles expanding as needed, then key one video layer over the other using the matte to reveal. You can animate graphic circles for the matte, as many as you like.

Comment: Thanks Jim, this is similar to what I was expecting but can you point me in the direction of how to create the matte? In my tests so far, I have created each circle on a seperate layer however this will be ridiculous to have to produce 100 or so layers

Comment: I'm not an AE maven so I can't give you specific directions, but there's likely a way to combine layers (mix down or render) each time you add, say, four layers. Then when you're done you have a single rendered layer you can import into your main project. Honestly, if I were doing this I'd write code (a script or similar) to create the circles but I'm not sure if AE can be scripted like that. Maybe someone else here knows.

Comment: There is. It's called pre-comping. It's been a while since I've done it, but if you check the docs for "pre comp" or "precompose" you should find more info.